# Failing to create mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table if it does not already exist in my database. For this I'm running this test which is working as intended:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa222", "twa222bg");
mysql_select_db("airline222", $conn) or die ("Database not found " . mysql_error() );
$val = mysql_query("SELECT 1 from '$FLIGHTID'");
```

However my problem comes when I try to create the table itself, which is giving me the following error: 
Problem with query: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''passenger' SMALLINT NOT NULL, 'booking' CHAR(6), 'seat' VARCHAR(3))' at line 2`

This is the code that is attempting to generate the table

```
if(!$val)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$FLIGHTID." (
    passenger SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    booking CHAR(6), seat VARCHAR(3) )";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Problem with query" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

I originally thought it was the ".$FLIGHTID." that was causing the problem but when I changed that to simply be ABC I still got the same error.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

**EDIT:**
My SQL output when using ABC is:

CREATE TABLE ABC ( passenger SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, booking CHAR(6), seat VARCHAR(3) )

Without using ABC it is:

CREATE TABLE ( passenger SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, booking CHAR(6), seat VARCHAR(3) )

Comment: Seems to work just fine. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b0e9

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL statement?

Comment: Is this really your code? Sure you don't use quotes around your column names like  `'passenger'` instead?

Comment: Don't use deprecated `mysql_*`, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: Btw you can shorten your code using create table if not exists instead of select and create. Also use bacticks to wrap column names (not single quotes) and use MySQLi or pdo libraries instead of the deprecated MySQL you are using

Comment: What is displayed when you echo $FLIGHTID ?

Comment: Just added the SQL output

Comment: You have to use backticks instead of single quotes and print the result of the whole statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use single quotes arround column names what is not allowed. Single qoutes indicates that the value inside is a litaral:

Change:

```
$val = mysql_query("SELECT 1 from '$FLIGHTID'");
```

to:

```
$val = mysql_query("SELECT 1 from $FLIGHTID");
```

Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`instead of deprecated `mysql_*` API.